# What should be the reason for not working linux system function properly?

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, snmp-trap

I'm checking one condition in my application where if the condition satisfies my job is to send one trap notification using the following command

```
snmptrap -c public -v 2c 192.168.1.104 "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.4.0
```

so in my application I was using function system as follows

```
system("snmptrap -c public -v 2c 192.168.1.104 "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.4.0");
```

but after using the `system` function I'm getting an error and the strange part is if I try to use the same command `snmptrap -c public -v 2c 192.168.1.104 "" 1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.4.0` in the console then it is working perfectly fine. Can anyone help me understand the reason behind this?

Comment: Typo: you need to 'escape' the two `"` characters in the command: `""` --> `\"\"` .

Comment: It looks like you have some quoting problems in that `system()` command: You're using double quotes (`"`) both on the outside of the command string and also within the command; that's going to cause confusion.

Comment: @G.M. yes you were right!!! Thanks a lot!!! you saved my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @G.M for the solution
So the following command worked for me

```
system("snmptrap -c public -v 2c 192.168.1.104 \"\" 1.3.6.1.4.1.53864.1.4.0");
```